# Role of math in science

Tags: soft-question, mathematics

Is it important for a physicist to be good at math? Should he be on par with a mathematician? According to me physics and math are like English and biology we study them in the same language but they are not same.

Answer (score 2):

Math is a tool for describing stuff in e.g. physics.

I could say "Energy conservation means that any change in internal energy must be exactly the same as all heat gained but withdrawn the work done".

Or I could say:

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

It is even hard to express in words without using words like "equal to", "added", "plus" and "minus". Math should be considered a language that make us able to very logically, densely and precisely to describe the world.

At some point in physics we deal with "infintely" many small changes. Integrals are tools to handle this. At some point we talk about instantaneous changes in e.g. velocity, and we us diffrentiation to handle this. Math is just a language as English - but much more strict and logic than any spoken language.